# Convergence of $\sqrt{n}(U_{n,1},U_{n,2})$ if each $U_n$ is uniform on the $n$-dimensional unit sphere (with hint)

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Problem 2.15 from "Mathematische statistiek" from A. van der Vaart, available [here](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/b.j.k.kleijn/AsympStat-LecNotes2010.pdf).

> For each $n$ let $U_n$ be uniformly distributed over the unit sphere $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that the vectors $\sqrt{n}(U_{n,1},U_{n,2})$ converge in distribution to a pair of independent standard normal variables as $n\rightarrow \infty$ [Use the previous problem].

In the link one can find the previous problem 2.14, but it is also here:

> Let $Z_1,...,Z_n$ be independent standard normal variables. Show that the vector $U=(Z_1,...,Z_n)/N$, where $N^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n Z_i^2$, is uniformly distributed over the unit sphere $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the sense that $U$ and $OU$ are identically distributed for every orthogonal transformation $O$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I don't see the link between problem 2.15 and 2.14. In problem 2.15 we have to show something about independent standard normal variables given some variables uniformly distributed in the unit sphere, and problem 2.14 is the opposite, there we have to show that a vector is uniformly distributed.

Further convergence of $\sqrt{n}$ times a vector makes me think of the multidimensional central limit theorem, but I can see no average.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Theres an average in teh definition of $U$.

Comment: @Batman I see $U$ has the sum $N^2$ in it and from this one can say that $U$ has an average of $Z_i^2$ in it. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hint: If $U_n=(Z_1,...,Z_n)/N_n$ with $N_n=\sqrt{Z_1^2+\cdots+Z_n^2}$, then what is $\sqrt{n}(U_{n,1},U_{n,2})$ equal to? And what can you say about the limit of $N_n/\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: @Did But if $U_n\sim Unif(S^{n-1})$, then how do we know that $U_n = (Z_1,...,Z_2)/N_n$?

Comment: You do not but you know that you can realize $U_n$ this way. Or, if you prefer, you know that this provides random variables with the correct distributions and since you are only interested in convergence in distribution, you may as well consider these.

Comment: Oh now I see something important: $U_n\sim Unif(S^{n-1}) \sim (Z_1,...,Z_2)/N_n$. Because we work with convergence in distribution, we may assume that $U_n = (Z_1,...,Z_n)/N_n$

Comment: The $\sqrt{n}$ is inviting me to think about the central limit theorem, but I think it's not needed. We have $\sqrt{n}U_{n,1} = \sqrt{n}Z_1/N_n = Z_1/\sqrt{(\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2/n)^{-1}}$. This goes to $Z_1$ in law, because the denominator goes to $1$ a.s. (law of large numbers, $Z_i\sim N(0,1)$, continuous mapping theorem).